# Search for duplicate cells within n + and - range of that cell

Tags: excel, range, highlight

Hello everyone and thank you for your time.

I have a large table (A:2 to F:270) that we use to communicate the production schedule for the week. I would like to highlight duplicate lot numbers in column A and then highlight the whole row.  Problem is, I only want it to compare within a certain range of each cell in column A (I don't want to compare it to the whole table).

For example, I would like the lot number in cell A11 looking for duplicates between A1:A21, and the lot number in cell A12 to look for duplicates between A2:A22 and cell A13 to look for duplicates between A3:A23. I can use conditional formatting of VBA whichever is easier

I have tried conditional formatting but it looks for duplicates throughout the entire table and highlights ALL duplicate lots numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra column that returns TRUE when the lot number in that row is a duplicate of the range around it using:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A21,A11)>1` for cell B11 in my example. It looks at the value in A11 and if it appears more than once in the neighbouring range, it returns TRUE. As you drag this formula down, the range will change e.g. cell B13 will be `=COUNTIF(A3:A23,A13)>1`.

You can then set up a conditional formatting rule to highlight the row when it equals TRUE.

[image]